# OpenCL – execution of dynamic for loops

Tags: loops, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu, cpu-architecture

How does for-loops in OpenCL kernels execute on the device when their boundaries are dynamic, i.e. when for each work-item the for-loop executes different amount of times?

---

AFAIK, a kernel is a set (or better said a stream) of instructions. The GPU device is set of independent compute units (stream multiprocessors – SM) each of which contain several compute units (stream processors – SP).

Each SM can load one instruction (for different SMs this could be different instructions) from the kernel (i.e. instruction stream) and execute the loaded instruction for as many work-items as there are SPs in the current SM (each SP operates the same instruction but with different data – SIMD).

All SPs in one SM must run the same instruction, therefore after executing the for-loop's condition, a dynamic decision must be made, based on the result of the condition for each work-item, what will be the next instruction to be run on the SM **and** for what work-items it'll be run for.

Based on this assumption, I'd assume that the `foobaz` kernel (see below) would execute faster, because when one work-item finishes executing, another work-item can take its place.

**Is this assumption wrong?**

---

**Which of the following two kernels, `foobar` and `foobaz`, would eventually execute faster?** What does the performance depend on? (The number of properties for one element can be order(s) of magnitude greater than for others).

`foobar`;

```
__kernel void foobar(__global int* elements,            /* size N          */
                     __global int* element_properties,  /* size N*constant */
                     __global int* output)              /* size N          */
{
    size_t gid  = get_global_id(0);
    int reduced = 0;

    for (size_t i=N*gid; i<N+N*gid; i++)
      reduce += predict_future_events( reduce, element_properties[i] );


    output[gid] = reduced;
}
```

… and `foobaz`;

```
__kernel void foobaz(__global int*  elements,                   /* size N       */
                     __global int*  element_properties,         /* size upper-bounded */
                     __global int2* element_properties_ranges,  /* size N       */
                     __global int*  output)                     /* size N       */
{
    size_t gid  = get_global_id(0);
    int reduced = 0;

    // `range.x` = starting index in `element_properties`
    // `range.y` = ending   index in `element_properties`
    int2 range = element_properties_ranges[gid]; 

    for (size_t i=range.x; i<range.y; i++)
      reduce += predict_future_events( reduce, element_properties[i] );


    output[gid] = reduced;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it is opencl 1.2 device,

If each "predict_future_events" is chaotic in terms of performance, you could check some "hardware optimized" changes. You could throw 2 different kernels at the same time(two different full-kernels(N) if they can be separated/independent) or you could push half of a kernel (N/2) as "constant version" and second half in a different kernel(as this will not be different from your 1st example computationally), maybe driver can handle some situations where one kernel delays forever but at least other half gets compute resource(if driver can do that). So more pipelines will be busy doing something and having better timing for kernels in the end.

Other than that, having a random latency per function makes it difficult to foresee which group of functions in a loop gives what  total latency so giving all threads equal number of steps(as in 1st example/constant) is easier to "assume" there will be a greater chance to have balanced load between threads.

For example, 1000-depth refraction + 1000-depth reflection for a ray-tracing kernel would be chaotic enough so you can just give 1 ray per thread to compute because you can't know if a ray will be refracted or reflected on the next surface(if there is any). Maybe grouping closer ones can use L1-L2 caches more often.

For opencl 2.0 device, you can spawn more threads/groups within kernel threads which should make this even more dynamic .

Answer (score 0):

You are doing almost the same thing in both solutions. My bet is they must done almost in equal time.

If you want to be faster, use the SIMD capabilities using int4 for your parameters and reduce variable, then adjust your predict_future_events function to process int4 values. In this way you can get up to 4x performance because each instruction process 4 elements in parallel.

Depending on your hardware, you can use int8 or up to int16.

BTW: I don't see where the N variable in assigned nor see any use of elements array.

Comment: I should probably state that both kernels are just pseudocode (so the absolute speedup isn't my concern at all). The core part however is, how does the *data-dependent* amount of loop-passes for each thread *versus* constant (but high number of) iterations for each thread affect the performance, and whether my assumption of how does the hardware (the GPU) handle the for-loop was correct.

Comment: What part is dynamic? range.y?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik yes. Well, actually I don't know neither `range.x` nor `range.y` for any particle beforehand, so both values are dynamic (I hope we mean the same thing by "dynamic"). Let's assume that the values in `element_properties_ranges` are produced by another kernel before executing `foobar` and `foobaz`.

Comment: @sarasvati so you asking if iterative load balancing is faster than a single kernel invocation?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I don't understand `other trying to change its range`. The context: First I run a kernel that sets values in `element_properties_ranges`. (Each `int2` value in `element_properties_ranges` represents start-end indices in `element_properties` for appropriate element of `elements`.). Then I run `foobaz`.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I'm sorry, I don't know what is `iterative load balancing`, but the `foobaz` kernel runs just once.

Comment: @sarasvati maybe I am confused. Are you asking 1 kernel(static, all array) vs M kernels with each having M/N threads(dynamic)? Does prediction function have a predictable performance?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik no, I mean something different. Are you willing to go to chat to discuss this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118763/discussion-between-huseyin-tugrul-buyukisik-and-sarasvati).